# Insert data into strongly normalized DB and maintain the integrity (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to develop a simple database for the phonebook. This is what I wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE phone
(
    phone_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    phone    CHAR(15),
    sub_id   INT,   -- subscriber id --
    cat_id   INT    -- category id --
);

CREATE TABLE category
(
    cat_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,    -- category id --
    cat_name CHAR(15)       -- category name --
);

CREATE TABLE  subscriber
(
    sub_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name    CHAR(20),
    fname   CHAR(20),   -- first name --
    lname   CHAR(20),   -- last name --
);

CREATE TABLE address
(
    addr_id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    country       CHAR(20),
    city          CHAR(20),
    street        CHAR(20),
    house_num     INT,
    apartment_num INT
);

-- many-to-many relation --
CREATE TABLE sub_link
(
    sub_id   INT REFERENCES subscriber(sub_id),
    addr_id  INT
);
```

I created a link table for many-to-many relation because few people can live at the same address and one person can live in different locations at different times.

But I cannot figure out how to add data in strongly normalized DB like this and maintain the integrity of the data.

The first improvement was that I added inique key on address table bacause this table should not contain duplicated data:

```
CREATE TABLE address
(
    addr_id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    country       CHAR(20),
    city          CHAR(20),
    street        CHAR(20),
    house_num     INT,
    apartment_num INT,
    UNIQUE (country, city, street, house_num, apartment_num)
);
```

Now the problem is how to add a new record about some person into DB. I think I should use the next order of actions:

1. Insert a record into `subscriber` table, because `sub_link` and `phone` tables must use id of a new subscriber.
2. Insert a record into `address` table because `addr_id` must exist before adding record into `sub_link`.
3. Link last records from `subscriber` and `address` in `sub_link` table. But at this step I have a new problem: how can I get `sub_id` and `addr_id` from steps 1) and 2) in PostgreSQL effectively?
4. Then I need to insert a record into the `phone` table. As at 3) step I dont know how to get `sub_id` from previous queries effectively.

I read about `WITH` block in the Postgres but I cannot figure out how to use it in my case.

**UPDATE**
I've done like `ASL` suggested:

```
-- First record --
WITH t0 AS (
    WITH t1 AS (
            INSERT INTO subscriber
            VALUES(DEFAULT, 'Twilight Sparkle', NULL, NULL)
            RETURNING sub_id
    ),
    t2 AS (
            INSERT INTO address
            VALUES(DEFAULT, 'Equestria', 'Ponyville', NULL, NULL, NULL)
            RETURNING addr_id 
    )
    INSERT INTO sub_link
    VALUES((SELECT sub_id FROM t1), (SELECT addr_id FROM t2))
)
INSERT INTO phone
VALUES (DEFAULT, '000000', (SELECT sub_id FROM t1), 1);
```

But I have an error: **WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top level
LINE 2: WITH t1 AS (INSERT INTO subscriber VALUES(DEFAULT,**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one query using a WITH block with a RETURNING clause. See [PostgreSQL docs on INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html). For example:

```
WITH t1 AS (INSERT INTO subscriber VALUES ... RETURNING sub_id),
t2 AS (INSERT INTO address VALUES ... RETURNING addr_id)
INSERT INTO sub_link VALUES ((SELECT sub_id FROM t1), (SELECT addr_id FROM t2))
```

Note that this simple form will only work when inserting a single row into each table.

This is somewhat off the topic of your question, but I suggest you also consider making sub_id and cat_id columns in the phone table foreign keys (use REFERENCES).

Comment: Does postgres allow performing two sequencing inserts in WITH block? Such like this: `INSERT INTO sub_link VALUES ((SELECT sub_id FROM t1), (SELECT addr_id FROM t2)), INSERT INTO phone VALUES (DEFAULT, "1111111", (SELECT sub_id FROM t1), ...`

Comment: Sure, just put all but the last INSERT into its own WITH block. Each WITH block can reference the aliases that came before it. E.g. `... t3 AS (INSERT INTO sub_link VALUES ((SELECT ... FROM t1), ...)) INSERT INTO phone ...`

Comment: Updated original post. The query becomes very complex. Using nested `WITH` block I got an error `WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top`

Comment: Don't nest your WITH statements, just put them one after the other. `WITH t1 AS (INSERT INTO subscriber ...), t2 AS (INSERT INTO address ...), t3 AS (INSERT INTO sub_link ...) INSERT INTO phone ...`

Answer (score 0):

You got the idea. Insert data from topmost tables so that you have their IDs before inserting references to them.

In PostgreSQL you can use `INSERT/UPDATE ... RETURNING id` construct. If you are not using some ORM which do it automatically, this may be useful.

The only thing here is that in step 2 you probably want to check if the address already exists before inserting:

```
SELECT addr_id FROM address WHERE country = ? AND city = ? ...
```